# Class not found when mysqlconnector is put as classpath

Tags: java, mysql

Here's my problem, I'm trying to connect a Java program to MySQL database. I'm using no IDE here. What happen is when i add the `mysql-connector-java-bin.jar` as CLASSPATH it produce error, but without CLASSPATH, my program runs but is not connected to the database because of the missing `com.mysql.jdbc.driver`. Any fix here? Thank you! Also even the basic HELLO WORLD program doesnt work when mysql connector is classpathed.

Here is the screenshot when I execute the program for clarifications.
[image]

Comment: Could you paste the code that is generating the error you show in the image?

Comment: There's no need for that I think. Error is obvious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is because you didn't put a ';' after then name of your connector jar file, Because the -classpath parameter value should be in ';' seperated format. The correct way is to use it in this way:

```
java -cp mysql-connector-java-5.1.23-bin.jar; Dbcon
```

Another problem you may encounter is when your class placed in a package. When using `java` command you must in the root of [bin] directory (root directory where your compiled classes exists) and make sure you are using the fully qualified name (full package name + class name) of your main class.

Good Luck.

Comment: @Anne Pauline Fernandez: Don't forget to up-vote the accepted answer ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Download **Connector/J** at here:

http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

And correct the connector path.

Answer (score 0):

When you specify a classpath with -cp option, it overrides current classpath settings. You are supplying a single claspath, which only contains mysql connector's classes. You should append your other classes' path to it so java could find your classes. The default classpath is current directory which is '.'

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html

Append other classpaths with a semicolon. Like:

java -cp whatever-mysql-connector.jar;your-classes-location